# Using mulerequester when there are more than one jms or wmq connector

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-el, anypoint-studio

This is continuation from [How to use Mule Expression in JMS:selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105973/how-to-use-mule-expression-in-jmsselector) but a different question. I am using mulerequester to read off the queue as shown below.

```
<mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="wmq://REPLY.QUEUE?selector=JMSCorrelationID%3D'#[sessionVars.myCorrelationId]'" doc:name="Mule Requester" timeout="120000"/>
```

It works if I have one wmqConnector but I have 2 wmq connectors in my mule project (wmqconnector and wmqconnector1), pointing to different servers. During runtime, when mulerequester resolve the URL given in the "resource", it encounters 2 connectors matching the wmq protocol and I get the following error message "There are at least 2 connectors matching protocol "wmq", so the connector to use must be specified on the endpoint using the 'connector' property/attribute. Connectors in your configuration that support "wmq" are: wmqConnector1, wmqConnector,  (java.lang.IllegalStateException)". I am not sure how to tell mulerequester which wmqConnector to use.

I referred to mule documentation for mulerequester but couldnt find any solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the connector as a uri Param like this:

```
<mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="jms://input?connector=AMQConnector1" doc:name="Request a message from a queue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my modified mulerequester as per Ryan's suggestion. It uses both connector and selector as Uri params.

```
 <mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="wmq://REPLY.QUEUE?connector=wmqConnector&amp;selector=JMSCorrelationID%3D'#[sessionVars.myCorrelationId]'" doc:name="Mule Requester" timeout="120000"/>
```